# React Application i18n support

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-i18next

We have a React application wherein all the labels of the widgets are read from the property file,

Property File:

```
export const properties = {
  dashboardcrumb_label: 'DASHBOARD',
  channelcrumb_label: 'CHANNELS',
    jobcard_header: 'JOBS',
    cancel_label: 'CANCEL'
  }
```

In js file usage(Example):

```
import { properties } from '../../../../resources/label_property'
<FlatButton label={properties.cancel_label}
```

Now we have a requirement to make it i18n compatible. please suggest an easier way to achieve i18n where I can reuse this property file with not much changes in js

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your component with `withNamespace` hoc as follows:

```
import { withNamespaces } from 'react-i18next';
// it would add 't' and 'lng' in the props
const { t } =this.props;
<FlatButton label={t('cancel_label')}
```

Personally I would suggest you to use [reaact-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl)